# Why is a Javascript XMLHttpObject sending a request with /None added?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a button for the user to log out. This requires a request being send to "/logout". But when I click the button, a request is send to "/logout?id=0.4523" (id is to prevent caching), but there's also one send to "/logout/None". How can I prevent this?

Here's my (simplified) code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById("logout").onclick=function(){
            var logout=new XMLHttpRequest();
            logout.open("GET","/logout/?id="+Math.random(),true);
            logout.send();
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="logout">Log Out</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That code does not have that effect. It looks like you simplified it too much. Please **test** your [mcve]s to make sure they do reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just guessing, but is this `<button>` associated to a `<form>`?

Comment: Appearently, "/logout/" was sending a request to "/logout/None". Problem solved.

Comment: It sounds like you're using Python on the server, and it's defaulting to `None` when there's no parameter.